# PIC:how can we get 1 ms interrupt using 16bit timer?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, frequency, timer

I am using **PIC24FJ256GB106** controller.I am setting configuration bit for internal frequency to **FNOSC_FRCPLL**.

I have confusion to this configuration bits that Am i getting 8MHZ or 16MHZ or 32MHZ ?

if I want timer(16bit) interrupt at every 1 ms then which frequency i have to use ? **FOSC or FCY**?

When i am setting **FNOSC_FRCPLL** configuration bit then what is **FOSC and FCY**?

Comment: Does the use of "???" and "????" increase the speed of transmission of the question over the internet?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh:I have done correction in my question.

Comment: Much better. Removed my downvote. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FNOSC_FRPLL means your ultimate clock will be the output of the PLL module.

[image]

[image]

Summarizing from the [PIC24F family reference manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39700a.pdf):

*6.8.3 FRC Oscillator with PLL Mode (FRCPLL)*

The output of the FRC postscaler block may also be combined with the 4x PLL to produce a nominal system clock of either 16 MHz or 32 MHz. Although somewhat less precise in frequency than using the Primary Oscillator with a crystal or resonator, it still allows high-speed operation of the device without the use of external oscillator components.

The FRCPLL mode is selected whenever the COSC bits are ‘001’. In addition, this mode only functions when the direct or divide-by-2 FRC postscaler options are selected (RCDIV2:RCDIV0 = 000 or 001).

Comment: :Thanks for yor replay.Please can you explain in detail.

Comment: I was on mobile earlier. Now I have access to more stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39897c.pdf), page 128, Figure 8-2 describes the clock configuration for your scenario. Since you have set FNOSC to the 8MHz internal clock with PLL, you'll need to set PLLDIV to divide by 2. Then, the system clock is determined by CPDIV (4, 8, 16, or 32MHz).

Whichever you pick, 4-32MHz, will be FOSC. FCY = FOSC / 2 for this device.

When configuring the timer, set TCS to the internal clock. This internal clock is the instruction clock, which will be FOSC/2 = FCY.